# How to install Mysqlpython connector on fedora 27

Tags: python-2.7, fedora, fedora-27

I am using fedora 27  and python 2.7 and I installed the last version of GCC but when I tried to install mysqlpython connector  by typing 'pip install mysqlpython' it show me an error.

> command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're missing the `python-devel` package:
`sudo dnf install python-devel -y`

It should be written in the last lines before the last error you've posted.